# Using RTK Query along with Redux Persistor

Tags: redux, react-hooks, react-redux, rtk-query, redux-persist

After spending large amount of time trying to fix this issue alone, I thought asking help from you guys. I have read so many issues regarding this but couldn't find anything helpful. I am trying to configure my store using both `persistor` and `RTK Query`.
this is my index.js file where I am trying to configure the store

```
const persistConfig = { key: "root", storage, version: 1 };

const persistReducers = persistReducer(persistConfig, authReducer);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [customApi.reducerPath]: customApi.reducer,
     persistReducers,
  },

  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }).concat(customApi.middleware),
});
setupListeners(store.dispatch);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistStore(store)}>
        <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

This is my `RTK Query`

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { REHYDRATE } from "redux-persist";

export const customApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: process.env.REACT_BASE_URL }),
  reducerPath: "customApi",
  tagTypes: ["RuralProjects"],
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getRuralProjects: build.query({
      query: () => "projects/ruralProjects",
      providesTags: ["RuralProjects"],
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetRuralProjectsQuery } = customApi;
```

This is my `authReducer`

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  user: null,
  token: null,
};

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setLogin: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload.user;
      state.token = action.payload.token;
    },
    setLogout: (state) => {
      state.user = null;
      state.token = null;
    },
  },
});

export const { setLogin, setLogout } = authSlice.actions;
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

The thing is without configuring the `RTK Query` in `store` my app is working. My question is how to use both `persistor` and `RTK Query` at the same time? Any help would be appreciated a lot!

How can I configure the store when I am using both the `redux persistor` and `RTK Query`

Comment: Please make sure that when using redux-persist with RTK Query you always have to [use extractRehydrationInfo](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/persistence-and-rehydration#redux-persist) or you risk running into memory leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell of the code it ***already is*** using both RTKQ and `redux-persist`... so I'm guessing you are really trying to ask a *different* question. If I am correct it seems you wanting to merge and also persist the `customApi` slice along with the `authSlice` state.

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from "redux-persist";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import authReducer from "../authSlice";
import { customApi } from "../customApi";

// Combine all slice reducers into a single root reducer
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  [customApi.reducerPath]: customApi.reducer,
  auth: authReducer,
});

const persistConfig = { key: "root", storage, version: 1 };

const reduxPersistActions = [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER];

// Persist the root reducer
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [...reduxPersistActions],
      },
    }).concat(customApi.middleware),
});

setupListeners(store.dispatch);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistStore(store)}>
        <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. My problem was in the `baseURL`.  I was getting that from .env file. After I hardcorded the baseURL, RTK Query started to get the data from the server. And also I have configured my store again simillar to your code. It also working. But now I have encountered a new problem. That is I cannot change the state in `authReducer`. I have tried to do it using useDispatch() but it is not working. Earlier it worked. This is my code. `dispatch( setLogin({ user: logged.user, token: logged.token,}));`

Comment: @AnusaraWeerasooriya So was your original issue that the queries just weren't working ***and not*** that you had any issue with persisting the redux store? If you've updated the store configuration similar to mine then the path to the auth state was changed a bit, but that shouldn't change how dispatched actions are handled in the `authReducer` function. This might be an extraneous issue better fit for a new SO post, with [mcve]. If you create a new post feel free to ping me here in a comment with a link to it and I can take a look when available.